# ASP.NET MVC 4 Paging parameter out of bounds

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a simple `ProductController` with one method, `List` that talks to a repository and does some simple paging.  The `List` method takes one parameter, an int to get the page currently being displayed by the view.  I'm trying to redirect the user to `/Product/List/1` if the parameter is more than the number of pages (based on the page size).  The paging part works, but I can't get the redirect to work if the user enters in a number larger than the number of total pages.  How can I accomplish this?  Current the app lets me enter in the parameter, and it displays nothing from the database.

EDIT: solved
 (but I would still like to know why it didn't work with my first attempt)

```
if (page > model.PagingInfo.TotalPages)
  {
        return RedirectToAction("List", new { page = 1 });
  }
```

Routes

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(null, url: "{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

PagingInfo

```
public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalPages
        {
            get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository _repository;
        public ProductController(IProductRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        public ActionResult List(int page =1)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel();
            model.Products = _repository.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductId)
                                        .Skip((page -1) * 4)
                                        .Take(4);
            model.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = 4,
                TotalItems = _repository.Products.Count()
            };
            //--> redirect logic
            if (page > model.PagingInfo.TotalPages)
            {
                RedirectToAction("List", "Product", new { page = 1 });
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        //doesn't work, added after first failed attempt


    }
public class ProductsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller code you have:

```
//--> redirect logic
if (page > model.PagingInfo.TotalPages)
{
    RedirectToAction("List", "Product", new { page = 1 });
}
return View(model);
```

Since you are not returning your `RedirectToAction`, your code will not stop processing. Your  `return View(model);` will still be executed.

Try returning your RedirectToAction instead:

```
//--> redirect logic
if (page > model.PagingInfo.TotalPages)
{
    return RedirectToAction("List", "Product", new { page = 1 });
}
return View(model);
```

Comment: That was my initial code, I figured it out (annotated above), but I'm not sure why it actually works.  I added the POST version of List after I couldn't get the first one to work.

Comment: Doesn't make sense that a POST would fix it because RedirectToAction makes the browser issue a 302 GET response.

Comment: Did you update your controller methods to return RedirectToAction?  The code you have posted above doesn't indicate that.

Comment: not sure if I followed you. I cleaned up the code a bit and indicated where I had my redirect logic (with the comment --> redirect logic)

Comment: now I see what you were saying.  In my project I did have return Redirect, but not on this question.  +1

Comment: So, was adding the `return` what solved the problem?